# facebook omniauth with devise not working

Tags: facebook, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

I used omniauth customized with devise for facebook signup  for my rails app.
when  go for "Sign in with facebook", it works for me as I am the one who created the
acebook app at acebook developers console.
but When someone else tries to use his acebook account, I get a message in Facebook page
 saying **"the developer hasn't created the app properly"**
Can anyone help me in fixing my Facebook app??

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps) Choose your app.
2. Go to Status
3. You will find 'Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?' change it to yes
4. You should be done